# Is it possible to compile multiple target files using CC compiler?

Tags: c, makefile, cc

I am using Minix 2.0.4 so I can't use gcc. I want to use one make file to compile multiple C programs, with multiple targets.

Here is the current state of my Makefile

```
CFLAGS  = -D_POSIX_SOURCE
LDFLAGS =
CC      = cc
LD      = cc

PROG    = prog1 prog2 
OBJS    = prog1.o prog2.o

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
         $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)

clean:
         rm -rf $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

However, when I try and use my makefile like this is get an error that says "prog2: can't compile, not transformation applies". Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think answered this once already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213584/creating-makefile-that-compiles-multiple-c-files-for-use-in-minix

Comment: I tried that and thought it worked at first, but it only compiled the first set of programs. It completely ignored OBJ2 and PROG2.

Comment: "make test" will make test. "make test2" will make test2. If you want "make" to make both, that's a different question.

Comment: Yes, if possible I would like to make both files at the same time by only running the command "make". Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, see the "all" target in the answer below. Without an argument, "make" will just make the first target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split it up this way:

```
PROG1 = test 
PROG2 = test2
OBJ1 = test.o
OBJ2 = test2.o


all: $(PROG1) $(PROG2)

$(PROG1): $(OBJ1) 
          $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ1) -o $(PROG1)
$(PROG2): $(OBJ2) 
          $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ2) -o $(PROG2)
```

etc

If all that subsitution makes you nervous, you can more simply say

```
all: test test1

test: test.o
      $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) test.o -o test
test2: test2.o
      $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) test2.o -o test2
```

And remove this from the beginning:

```
PROG1 = test 
PROG2 = test2
OBJ1 = test.o
OBJ2 = test2.o
```

There are other shortcuts, but this more specific and obvious.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help again. I ran across all: before but assume it was only in gcc.

Comment: This is nothing special about the target "all". It just happens to be the first target in the Makefile so "make" with no arguments makes it.

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly and only what you are asking, you do not need any Makefile at all.  GNU Make has "built-in rules" for what you want:

```
> ls Makefile
ls: cannot access Makefile: No such file or directory
> make prog1 prog2
cc   prog1.o   -o prog1
cc   prog2.o   -o prog2
```

By the way, in general,

```
> make prog1 prog2
```

is subtly different, from having an additional `all: prog1 prog2` target, and doing

```
> make all
```

The former makes the first target and then the second, completely independently, as if in two successive invocations.  The second, makes them in one invocation: probably faster for large makefiles, possibly in parallel if invoked with `-j ...`, and possibly with different messages output.